# int not initialized compilation error

Tags: java, int

Ok, so I searched for a similar thread like this one but couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.

I'm trying to program something that generates random numbers and turns them into a question.
I'm not even sure it's even properly written but I'm having a compilation error.

"Variable answer1 might not have been initialized"

Here's the code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class random{
    public static void main (String [] args){

        System.out.println("Random number generated");

        Random obj= new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int answer1;
        int rgen= obj.nextInt(100);
        int rgen1= obj.nextInt(1000);


        System.out.println(rgen + " + " + rgen1 + " = ? ");
        scan.nextInt();
        if (answer1 == rgen + rgen1)
        System.out.println("Correct");
        else
        System.out.println("Wrong");


    }
}
```

Comment: Annnnnd ... it's never initialized. What is confusing you about the error message?  You declare it, don't initialize it, then attempt to use it in your `if` statement.

Comment: This is a tough game, it may take a while to win it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Define `answer1` to be some initial value.

```
int answer1 = 0;
```

You can't use a variable that you haven't initialized, which is what you attempt to do with `if (answer1 == rgen + rgen1)`.

It'd likely be that you want to read in the next integer, so you could also do this:

```
int answer1 = scan.nextInt();
```

Or, before you hit your `if` block, you can change the statement of `scan` to put the value into the variable instead:

```
answer1 = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: How do I do that? And why do people vote down my thread? :/ --EDIT -- oh thanks!

Comment: @EdwardHiroko "int answer1 = 0;"

Comment: Any idea how to make my random generator last forever? if the user inserts the wrong answer it will print the same question and if the user has inserted the correct one, then the system will generate another random math question... ? possible?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want this:

```
answer1 = scan.nextInt();
```

Otherwise, the call of `scan.nextInt()` reads and discards the value, while `answer1` remains uninitialized. You should probably combine initialization with declaration, too: remove

```
int answer1;
```

and replace it with

```
int answer1 = scan.nextInt();
```

on the line where you read the int from the `Scanner`.

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
int answer1;
```

reserves space on the stack for that variable. It doesn't put anything in there, so whatever is in that variable is whatever was in memory at that location at the time.

It hasn't been initialized because you haven't put anything in there yet. The warning will go away if you change it to

```
int answer1 = 0;
```

But honestly I'm not sure what your code is trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! it works, and my code is trying to generate random numbers and then prints them in a math question like "50 + 400", now if the answer is 450 then it'll print "correct", if it's not, it'd print "wrong".